# selectpicker not working when append tr from existing table to other table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to create dynamic table from existing table structure, by appending existing table's tr tag with new table. For every select picker shows correct options but when I select option value its not working(Its not selecting any value).

Below code is for appending existing table's  to new table:
arrayFields- all tr tag ids from existing table.
res_table_sorted- new table.
res_table - existing table.

I have tried many solutions from SO but they didn't work.

```
for (i = 0; i <= count; i++){
    $("#res_table_sorted tbody").append($("#" + arrayFields[i]));
    }
    var customFields = $("#cust-field-wrap").html();

    $("#res_table_sorted tbody").append(customFields);
    var row = $("#res_table_sorted tbody").html();
    $('#res_table tbody').html('');
    $('#res_table tbody').append('<tr>' + row + '</tr>');
    $("#res_table_sorted tbody").html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before. Always put `$('selectpickbox').selectpicker('refresh');` at the end of your code.